# Escape characters - How to delete a portion of a line

Tags: python, terminal

I'm messing around with escape chars with python 3 on a linux system.

By using `sys.stdout.write('\x1b[<char>')` I can perform various operations such as move the cursor to a particular position (`[<row>;<column>H`),
change the font color (`[<number>m`) and so on.

These three sequences deal with line erasing:

```
[ K = erase from current cursor position (ccp) to the end of the line
[ 1K = erase from ccp to the start of the line
[ 2K = erase whole line
```

Which are fine, but what about erasing a specific segment of the line, let's say from column 3 to column 7?

I looked into `man console codes` but I can't find anything besides those 3 sequences above. Is there a way to do this?

--UPDATE--
Thanks to the suggestion of joel goldstick below, I think found a workaround:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2;1H') #moves the cursor to r 2, c 1 and sets home
sys.stdout.write('01234567890123456789') #prints 20 characters
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2;5H') #place the cursor to r 2, c 5
sys.stdout.write('     ') # write 5 spaces to "delete" from c5 to c10
```

Comment: I found this reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes.  It looks like you would have to send repeated delete commands and know how many characters you want to delete

Comment: ahh, nice! I think I found the solution, check the update edit